# Oprofile vs perf

Tags: c++, linux, profiling

I am looking a system-wide sampling profilers for Linux. Both perf and OPrfile work off the same hardware counters so I am not sure what the difference between the two are.

So what are the differences between perf and OProfile and when will you use one or the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perf seems to be easier to install and run - going by my limited experience.

Here's a link that might be useful: http://rhaas.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/perf-good-bad-ugly.html

Both can produce call graphs, annotated assembly/source code, kernel level event sampling, etc. I don't see a big difference between them (not that I have used either of them much as of yet).

Comment: One difference is that `operf` allows you to view a line-by-line profile of your code: `operf ./name-of-binary` and then `opannotate --source`. As far as I'm aware `perf` currently has no way to remove the assembly code from the annotations, which make the source code quite hard to read.